# Finite groups with a cyclic maximal subgroup.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

In the book **A Course in the Theory of Groups** by **Derek J.S. Robinson**, Finite $p$-groups with a cyclic maximal subgroup are classified.

Now I wish to know whether finite groups with a cyclic maximal subgroup are classified?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. This paper " V. V. Pylaev, N. F. Kuzennyi, Finite groups with a cyclic maximal subgroup, Ukrainian Mathematical Journal, 28 (5) (1976), 500--506", classify finite groups with a cyclic maximal subgroup.

Comment: I need another reference since I am unable to access this one.

Comment: @user93432 I dont have another reference. We can see the fist two page of the paper in internet and also can be save as image. This two page contain the main theorem. But it does not contain the proof. See this link. http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01095210#page-1